# Zoom to point cluster on click in arcgis api javascript

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I have tried this.

```
map.add(pointLayer);

pointLayer.on("click", function (event) {

    pointLayer.event.graphic

    map.centerAndZoom(event.graphic.geometry, 4);
});
```

but it is not executed. I am trying to create a function on click event.

Comment: Hi, I am guessing that the code line `pointLayer.event.graphic` in the function is a mistake .. Except that, it looks OK

Comment: Hi Developer, I'll give you a couple of advice: 1) specify the versions of the JS API (in this case 3.x) and 2) try to share some code to help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is that you are treating `event.graphic.geometry` as a [Point](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/point-amd.html), which is what [map.centerAndZoom](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/map-amd.html#centerandzoom) is expecting, but if you print it out you will realize it is not:

```json
{
    "x": -9177389.169799313,
    "y": 4247317.642662031,
    "spatialReference": {
        "wkid": 102100
    }
}
```

So, you would have to create a point like this:

```js
map.addLayer(pointLayer);
    
pointLayer.on("click", function (event) {
  map.centerAndZoom(new Point(event.graphic.geometry),18);
});
```

Here you can see [a live demo using ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3.x](https://jsbin.com/hufuwim/edit?html,output).

If you have the chance, I highly recommend you to start [using 4.x](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/) as soon as possible. Just in case anyone needs it, here is the [same demo using ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4.x](https://jsbin.com/pemoqem/2/edit?html,output) (and ESM modules).